# Providing Access to a Whitelisted Server through OpenVPN

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

There's a server A. This server is only accessible from another server B, with a given IP address. I want to install OpenVPN on server B so that clients connecting to this VPN can access server A as well.

If I understand correctly, the OpenVPN should be bridged, am I correct? Any advise on how to do this? An online tutorial maybe? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.